# CakePHP Is it possible to pass dynamic data to an element for use across an entire site?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

With this project I'm working on, the header contains menu items that have drop downs showing relevant items to the selected menu item. These items are intended to be pulled straight from the database, so items can be added/removed whenever it's needed.

My question is how would this work when I used an Element with CakePHP? I understand that an element is a bit of reusable code, but I'm not sure where the logic code should be placed? Does an element use it's own controller, or do I have to add the code to every single controller that's active on the project?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have an element for a dinamic menu with the companies that the page represents, and i use it in the layout since it is needed to show in every page.

What i do is the following: in the app controller in a beforeFilter (you may use before render or anything that calls before the views is rendered) i do the logic part. something like this

```
$this->loadModel('Company');
$companies = $this->Company->find('all');
$this->set('companies', $companies);
```

with that you may use it in your views/layout/elements

hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll use the element for the piece of the view that you want to show on each page. You do not want to break with MVC and mix business logic in the views.

Inside your element do a call to a controller action using requestAction(). Have a read of this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements this will explain you how to use requestAction().

It sounds like that you want to build a menu or something. So call the controller that deals with the menus and get the data from the model.

Answer (score 2):

An element is basically a mini view that can be included in other views. You can create controllers for elements or you can add your logic to the controller that includes the element. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1081/Elements